# Shiny ui not recognized

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the normal template for shiny:

```
library(shiny) 
ui <- fluidPage(
      #a lot of inputs, graphs, also uiOutput()    
) 
server <- function(input, output){    
      #sourcing and running function to generate output, making graphs    
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When using the "Run App"-Button, deploying to shinyapps.io or selecting all code and running it, `ui` is not read in properly. It does not appear in the environment and the error message *Error in force(ui) : object 'ui' not found* is printed.

When running the code line-by-line however it works fine.

I found this post, where someone had the same error message: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-in-force-ui-object-ui-not-found-when-deploying-app-to-server/34027, but their solution (removing `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)`) did not work for me.

Comment: It is working in my machine.

Comment: The template usually does for me as well, I guess it might be an issue of too complex code in the ui. I did not want to post more than 300 lines of code here though. Can that be?

Comment: I try to run your code, when I don't copy the entire `ui`, it throws the same error as you did. Please try to choose the whole code and run again. Then see how it is.

Comment: Are you able to run the app if you run each component of the 300+lines of code rather than using the run button? Could you have a misplaced end parenthesis?

Comment: @SusanSwitzer : Yes. As said in the question if I run it line by line it works. ui does appear in the environment and the App runs without issues. (I'm done with it otherwise). Also when using Strg+Enter/Run while the cursor is in the line where ui starts, it jumps right to the end of ui, so parenthesis seem not to be the issue.

Comment: @ThoVu : I don't quite understand what you mean. I have tried disabling parts of the ui now. Even when I disable the entire content of ui it does not assign it properly.

Comment: I mean we sometimes we don't copy from the beginning to the end of the chunk of code, then we miss a couple of lines in the `ui`. It will throw the same error.

Comment: I have found it. Thank you very much for helping. I guess it was one of these errors where discussion and explaining to others helps!

Answer (score 0):

After I disabled all the complex code inside `server` and `ui`, to make it match the example the error still occurred. The issue was in the code above the actual app.

I had used this line before defining `ui` and `server`:

```
 X<-function(){} #making an empty function so the one from another script is not underlined
```

When commenting this out the code worked.

Comment: I hope this can help others searching this error message.